Is there a way to focus on search bars (of search engines) using C#?
I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, anyways I am using .NET Framework in C# and the idea is for the code to handle the search bars only and not the rest of the page the user is visiting.
We are required to build a keylogger for our project using C# and that is one of the requirements. The specific request was "I want the keylogger to capture what is typed onto the search bar only and it should not be able to capture credentials or anything else the user wants to do".
I did my research and honestly, I couldn't find much. Thanks (and sorry) in advance.

What you are asking sounds like using events on a form controller.
